# Splitting NSString doesn't work in Swift

Tags: string, swift, nsstring

I have a long string i need split into an array by splitting when "|||" is found

I can split a String using two ways i found at SO

First one is this

```
 func split(splitter: String) -> Array<String> {
    let regEx = NSRegularExpression(pattern: splitter, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(), error: nil)!
    let stop = "<SomeStringThatYouDoNotExpectToOccurInSelf>"
    let modifiedString = regEx.stringByReplacingMatchesInString (self, options: NSMatchingOptions(),
        range: NSMakeRange(0, count(self)),
        withTemplate:stop)
    return modifiedString.componentsSeparatedByString(stop)
}
```

Second one is this

```
var splt = str.componentsSeparatedByString("[\\x7C][\\x7C][\\x7C]")
```

I tried using the delimiter as both "[\x7C][\x7C][\x7C]" and "|||" and i tried using both String and NSString

Nothing seems to work though, i just get an array with the original string in it

Comment: var splt = str.componentsSeparatedByString("|||") Should work,and the army is spot

Comment: And what do you want to do? Where does this string come from?

Comment: `var splits = "aosd|||aoisnd|||aipsnd".componentsSeparatedByString("|||")` **does** work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func split(splitter: String) -> [String] {
    return splitter.componentsSeparatedByString("|||")
}
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer even though it's what i was doing, because what i was doing was c orrect. The error was that i was using "|||" rather than the characters from the String and apparently they werent the same character (even though they should have been)